# Calculating tensor products

Tags: tensor-products

How can you find whether the tensor product of $\mathbb {Q}\otimes\mathbb{Q/Z}$ is finite?

Comment: Do you know about torsion?

Comment: See Example 3.6 of https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf.